# Angular - how to use ng-repeat value as variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to leverage "column" as a number and re-use it to define the "colspan" in the following "td".

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
            {{column}}
        </td>
        <td colspan="column">
            Something
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe ... <td colspan="{{column}}">

Comment: @rfornal thanks but no, you can't use {{column}} cause it's outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if thats what you meant but you can try the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat-start="column in columns">
            {{column}}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat-end colspan="{{column}}">
            Something
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although, if for example "column" is 5, that is going to show 5 times <td colspan="">. Only need 1 <td> and its colspan should be 5.

Comment: thats what it is.. 1 td with colspan 5